# VirtualBox in Ubuntu doesn't show menu bar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to import `.ova` file to virtual machine but something goes wrong and there is no menu bar (need to get `File`, `Machine`, `New`, `Settings` etc, like in this screen:

[Oracle VMBox View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyspn.png)

so my virtualbox looks like:

[Ubuntu View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovttD.png)

how it it possible to display menu?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the menus are on the top edge of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Do you see there any menu? :)

Comment: @joepaulens, yes. Added a screenshot.